# Trap MySQL Exception in Glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have avoided the problem so far of trapping specific MySQL Exceptions as `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`, etc. But now I need it to tell the user that he is violating a constraint and should choose a different string key. I've tried to catch the specific exception by using `instanceof` operator, since Glassfish is wrapping it in a `EJBException`. But I haven't managed to do this so far.

Does anyone have the correct code/pattern to catch the specific SQL exception in an application container as Glassfish ?

Best Regards Chris.

PS. I am using Glassfish 3.1 and JPA 2.0

Comment: Are you using JPA? Or some other framework/library/API?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: I updated the post with the persistence library information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most database-access frameworks, libraries or APIs it is impossible to predict all of the scenarios that would result in failures.

In JPA, there are exceptions in the API that map to commonly failures encountered failures. Most of these exceptions are instances of the [`PersistenceException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html) class, or it's sub-classes like [`EntityExistsException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityExistsException.html), [`EntityNotFoundException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException.html), [`NonUniqueResultException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NonUniqueResultException.html) etc. You could catch these specific exceptions and issue appropriate error messages.

You may also use the [Bean Validation API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/package-summary.html), to verify the state of your JPA entities before persisting them, so that you could reduce the possibilities of catching exceptions that will require different error messages and resulting corrective actions by an end-user.

Comment: None of the standard exceptions (if I understand correctly) in the Persistence API will be thown in the case of a violation of a constraint. I could always do a find/checkup before. but I want to try to avoid a lot of extra queries to the database, for something as normal as the error code for a validation of a constraint. Will try it later again. Thanks for the replay.

Comment: @Chris, it depends on the constraint you have defined. `EntityExistsException` will always be thrown for a primary key violation. If you have defined other constraints, then you might still have the `PersistenceException` thrown, whose cause might be a `SQLException`. As long as you know the mappings between the SQL error codes and the conditions in your application that have been violated, you can still continue to generate messages that can be read by end users.

Comment: It's not a primary or foreign key, only a unique constraint. So will a EntityExistsException be thrown ?

Comment: @Chris, no it won't be thrown. I believe a PersistenceException would be thrown in such a case. You will need to recurse through the exception stack using `getCause()` method, until you arrive at a SQLException instance. Then you might be able to map a SQLError code against a human-readable message.